# MS Word - discrete scrolling

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way, wile working on a document in two-page view, to

- use only discrete (page-level) scrolling
- and hide the margins?

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, which works as you'd expect in two-pages view.

Hiding margins in two-pages view is not possible as it only applies to the self-described Print Layout view.